Forbid certain changes on Android
I often face the following problem: an old person, absolutely not tech-savvy, is using an Android phone and is not contactable anymore because he/she has inadvertently muted its phone which doesn't ring anymore when one calls him/her, or has turned it off and doesn't know how to turn it on again. More generally, he/she has inadvertently changed any setting, the change leading to more difficult use of the phone for him/her.
I would like to prevent that kind of issue by forbidding that kind of changes and ideally, natively. That is, without installing a new app -- because I saw apps allowing macro programming or even remote control, but I don't want processes running on that person's phone, nor do I want to control his/her phone on a regular basis to reinstate correct settings. (Except if there's no reliable native solution.) The phone in question is a Samsung Galaxy S10+ under Android 12.
Is there something standard regarding this matter?

While not necessarily the same, you also might be interested in [tag:parental-control]. However, AFAIK, Android doesn't provide a standard for restricting its own device, even like parental control. Some manufacturers may add customization, like Easy Mode on Samsung, but not a fully customizable setting restriction. This is also usually a matter for enterprise MDM (Mobile Device Management), but not really applicable for personal usage.

Are there free MDM software available on Android btw ? (Because this in indeed the exact need.)
